# I am using syncState and I am observing that State is not updating instantly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

when I update the state and in next line I want to access the state i am not getting data.

```
setSelectedSalvo(salvo);
setAppState((s) => {
    s.selectedSalvo= salvo
    s.openSalvoTypechangeDialog = e.currentTarget;
});
console.log('salvo type ', selectedSalvo?.global);
setSelectedSalvo((s)=>{s.global = !selectedSalvo.global})
console.log('salvo type after state update', selectedSalvo);
```

I want to get updated State

Comment: State variables get updated on rerender.  This is *the* fundamental basis of declarative React state.

Comment: What is _"syncState"_? Never heard of it and a search doesn't turn up anything much